# How to upload files and Json data at same time from angularJS to MVC?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an object like this:

```
var user= {
  name:"test",
  lastname: "test1"
  year: "52"
}
```

and array of files:

```
var files= [];
files.push(
    $scope.file1,
    $scope.file2,
    $scope.file3,
);
```

I'm triying upload the array file and the json data with this code:

```
$http({
     url: '/Create/User',
     method: 'POST',                
     data: {model: angular.toJson(user), files: files}, // {model: user, files: files}
     headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },         
     transformRequest: function(data) {
     var formData = new FormData();                    
     formData.append("model", data.model);
     for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
         formData.append("files[" + i + "]", data.files[i]);
     }                   
     return formData;
     },       
 })
```

When I send the data, I just get the files but the value in the model is null, what I'm doing wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult User(UserVM model, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

I'm using angular version 1.5.7. Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried with `model: JSON.stringify(user)`? Also, why your `header` has  `{ 'Content-Type': undefined }`?

Comment: Yes I tried with JSON.stringify, but not works. When I use { 'Content-Type': undefined } or { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} I can share the files to my method but the model is null. If I use { contentType: "application/json"} I can share the model with data, but the files are null. I don't know what happend. I've saw some examples, but not works for me.

Comment: well, can you `POST` your data in 2 requests? here your content types are different. that's why you are facing issues I guess. one is `json` and another is `form-data`

Comment: Thanks I'll have to do that...  :/